# Reactjs: How to pass name, value to Material ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

I am using material ui autocomolete. I want to pass name, value and onchange on autocomplete, the same way we do for TextField. How to do achieve that. ?? My code is not working.

```
              <Autocomplete
                id="combo-box-demo"
                fullWidth
                options={props.propsmaster}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.abc || option.xyz}
                size="small"
                              
                renderInput={(params) =>
                  <TextField 
                  {...params}  
                  label={propsMain.abc} 
                  variant="outlined"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={(e) => exhandleChange(e)}
                  value={values.name}
                  />
                }                 
              />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        fullWidth
        options={props.propsmaster}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.abc || option.xyz}
        size="small"
        name="name"
        onChange={(e) => exhandleChange(e)}
        value={values.name}       
        renderInput={(params) =>
          <TextField 
          {...params}  
          label={propsMain.abc} 
          variant="outlined"
          
          />
        }                 
      />
```